# ntwitter: stop listening on stream events after X callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-streaming-api, ntwitter

//Totally new to node.js

I'm using ntwitter to listen on twitter statuses. How can I stop listening after X callback were called?

```
 var twittsCounter = 0;
 twit.stream('statuses/filter', {track:['cool','awesome','fuck yeah!']}, function(stream) {
  stream.on('data', function (tweet) {
    twittsCounter += 1;
    console.log(twittsCounter + ":" + tweet.text);
    if (twittsCounter > 100){
      //stop listening? 
    }

  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factor your event handler into a separate function. Then use

```
stream.on('data', myDataHandler)
```

... and in `myDataHandler` just use `stream.removeListener('data', myDataHandler)`.

`stream` is "just" an `EventEmitter`, here are the docs: http://nodejs.org/api/events.html